# Entifyframework core 2.0 filter in ThenInclude

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

I am using EF core 2.0 and would like to filter the child collection. Can anyone help me how to do this in EF core 2.0?

```
    var items = await _context.RiskType
                              .Include(r => r.Categories)
                              .ThenInclude(category => category.Alerts)
                              .ToListAsync();
```

In the above code i want to filter `category.Alerts.where(alert=>alert.caseId==1)`

Thanks

Comment: Not supported yet. See [Support filtered Include #1833](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833) request.

Answer (score 1):

As said in one of the comments this is not yet supported. However you can get around it in a bunch of ways.

First you can .Select() the needed data into an anonymous or DTO object and work with it. Note that in the sample code below the .Include() is ignored by EF Core because there is a .Select() method. However i like to use it for clarity.

```
Parent[] parents = context.Parent
                          .Include(p => p.Children)
                          .Select(p => new 
                           {
                               FilteredChildren = p.Children.Where(/*Filter Func for the children collection*/) 
                           })
                          .ToArray();
```

The other way is to explicit load entities for a certain Parent that you need. This is good when you have to load children for only some of the parents but if you have a big collection and want to load all children have in mind that the explicit loading takes a trip to the database. In the code sample below you say that you want to .Load() a .Collection() for a Parent entry and if you want to filter it you must use .Query() so you can get the query that would be used to obtain the entities and apply filter with .Where() method. In the end you just have to say .Load() to load the children entities in the Parent entity. If you want to use Explicit loading for a navigation property that is not a collection you have to use .Reference() method instead of .Collection().

```
Parent parent = context.Parents.Find(/*Key*/);

context.Entry(parent)
       .Collection(p => p.Children)
       .Query()
       .Where(/*Filter Func for the children collection*/)
       .Load()
```

I am fairly new to EF and if someone has more suggestions i would like to look at them.

Answer (score 1):

Use EF plus and this works. You may filter on either level. 
https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter

```
var items = ctx.RiskType.IncludeFilter(r=>r.Categories).IncludeFilter(x => x.Categories.Select(p=>p.Alerts.Where(alert=>alert.caseId==1)))
                     .ToList();
```

This works like Include with filter which applies on database level (you see it in db profiler).